# Is there any way to display custom UI below player controls of AVPlayerController in Apple TV?

Tags: tvos, apple-tv, avplayerviewcontroller

I needs to display a player UI similar to Youtube so that I can display some assets below the player controls. How can we achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

I was not receiving Siri remote events on customising the Avplayercontroller. So we were implementing fully customised player solution by using Avplayer